# Similarity of Two Line/Dis -similarity of two lines

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics

Consider there are these two lines . Red and Blue .

[image]
Red line ranges from 1-10 at y -axis

Blue line ranges from 17-19 at y-axis

Both are of the same length at x- axis.

What is the mechanism to find out if the two lines are similar or dissimilar?

Edit - Normalising the two lines is the last trick in kitty!

Comment: I think you need to define similarlity. They look similar (at a macro level) because their shape is almost identical, but they are never equal, and at the micro level they may not be similar.

Comment: I would say by similar I meant they are within the same phase